# Sqlite&Python: Exiting for loop

Tags: python, sqlite, loops

Can someone please explain why the first loop gets exited, when the second loop is done.
First i get all table names in database(Total 4 results)
Then i want to get all data from that table.

But i only get the data from the first table for some reason.
If i remove the loop that gets the data from the table, then it runs the first for loop all the way to the end.

```
#Get all tables in database file
for tablename in c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';"):
    print(tablename[0])

    for elementdate in c.execute('SELECT * FROM %s ORDER BY Date DESC' % tablename[0]):
        print(elementdate)

Output:
table_1
(1, '20120210', 360)
(2, '20100210', 204)
Loop Excited
```

Same code just without last for loop

```
#Get table names
for tablename in c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';"):
    print(tablename[0])

    #for elementdate in c.execute('SELECT * FROM %s ORDER BY Date DESC' % tablename[0]):
    #   print(elementdate)

Output:
table_1
table_2
table_3
table_4
Loop Excited
```

Have i found an error or am i just dumb?

Comment: what is `tablename` content?

Comment: Is `c` a database cursor? In this case, you are trying to nest multiple queries on the same cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't execute few queries in the same cursor before fetching results of first one:

```
c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
tables = c.fetchall()
for tablename in tables:
    print(tablename[0])
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM %s ORDER BY Date DESC' % tablename[0])
    for elementdate in c.fetchall():
        print(elementdate)
```

Answer (score 1):

A single cursor object works only with a single query at a time; `execute()` overwrites any previous results.

If you want to execute two queries at the same time, use two cursors:

```
c = db.cursor()
c2 = db.cursor()
for row in c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'"):
    tablename = row[0]
    for row2 in c2.execute("SELECT * FROM %s ORDER BY Date DESC" % tablename):
        ...
```

Note: it would be a bad idea to modify the table while some other query on it is still running.

Comment: I see, never actually knew what the cursor was for, but now it makes sense.